# Anchor links in iframe with fixed height don't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe embedded in my page. This iframe contains an other page with a few sections and anchor links to corresponding sections (jump to links). The height of iframe is controlled with JS through "message" event.

```
<style>
 .my-iframe { 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 }
</style>

<iframe class="my-iframe" src="https:/my-iframe/" title="My iframe" ></iframe>

<script>
 const frame = document.querySelector('.my-iframe');
 window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
 frame.style.height = e.data.params.height + 'px'
 })
</script>
```

The problem is, after setting the iframe height from JS, the anchor links in it stop working, but when i remove dynamic height and leave it on default value, links work just fine.
The height value from event data is equal to the page height which is embedded in with iframe, can it be too much and cause the links not to work?

Comment: I tried to change height to the value which is less than the actual page height and it started working. Also scrollbar appeared.
The page is not under my control, it is provided by partner. 
One solution i can imagine is to set height to 100vh and allow scrolling within the iframe, so the links also will work. 
But that seems bad from the UX perspective, as my page has it's header and footer.

Comment: Maybe on that third-party page there's some obscure CSS moving a transparent cover over the links depending on the size of the view, or pointer events of the links are disabled, or anything ... Without seeing the code and CSS of that page everything is just speculation. You can try to check the above mentioned situations by navigating and triggering links on the keyboard.

Comment: try giving it a height using some other unit, e.g. `height: 100vh;`